# How does Python add Typing hints to classes?

Tags: python, python-typing

There is such a demand, I have a create_connnection function, the conn_constructor can be any one of SqlLiteConnection, PGsqlConnection, MysqlConnection, etc.

What typing hints can I add to the conn_constructor parameter to implement, what class is the parameter, and what class is the return value an instance of?

Obviously, Any is not a good thing, because the code completion of the IDE is lost

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from abc import abstractclassmethod
from typing import Any


class BaseConnection:
    @abstractmethod
    def connect(self):
        pass


class MysqlConnection(BaseConnection):
    def connect(self):
        pass


class PGsqlConnection(BaseConnection):
    def connect(self):
        pass


class SqlLiteConnection(BaseConnection):
    def connect(self):
        pass


def create_connnection(conn_constructor: Any) -> Any:
    return conn_constructor()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = create_connnection(conn=SqlLiteConnection)
```

Comment: What you've shown can't work, that's not the name of the argument. It seems like you're intending to accept a class and return an instance of it, so did you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `TypeVar`

```py
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Type, TypeVar


class BaseConnection:
    @abstractmethod
    def connect(self):
        pass


class MysqlConnection(BaseConnection):
    def connect(self):
        pass


class PGsqlConnection(BaseConnection):
    def connect(self):
        pass


class SqlLiteConnection(BaseConnection):
    def connect(self):
        pass


ConnT = TypeVar("ConnT", bound=BaseConnection)


def create_connnection(conn_constructor: Type[ConnT]) -> ConnT:
    return conn_constructor()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = create_connnection(SqlLiteConnection)
```

See it working https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=1afc3a41adf2ca4be75d6273b9d26c0d

Answer (score -1):

Use `conn_constructor: Type[ConnConstructor]`

The `typing hint` of `conn_constructor` is not `ConnConstructor`, but `type`, but just writing `type` is too `typing less`, so we can use square brackets `Type[ConnConstructor]`

In this way, there will be no automatic completion of the IDE alone!

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from abc import abstractclassmethod
from typing import Type

ConnConstructor = TypeVar('ConnConstructor')


class BaseConnection:
    @abstractmethod
    def connect(self):
        pass


class MysqlConnection(BaseConnection):
    def connect(self):
        pass


class PGsqlConnection(BaseConnection):
    def connect(self):
        pass


class SqlLiteConnection(BaseConnection):
    def connect(self):
        pass


def create_connnection(conn_constructor: Type[ConnConstructor]) -> ConnConstructor:
    return conn_constructor()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = create_connnection(conn_constructor=SqlLiteConnection)

    connection.connect()
```

Comment: What exactly is _"too `typing less`"_?